# Hay forma de saber cuantos usuarios están utilizando mi app en tiempo real?

Tags: android-studio

Buen día a todos, actualmente necesito saber cuantos usuarios utilizar mi aplicación en Android originalmente necesito que sea una validación por cada base de datos a que me refiero con esto? pues mi aplicación se conecta a diferentes bases de datos al iniciar entonces por ejemplo si yo he autorizado el acceso a 5 usuarios para la base de datos A cuando trate de acceder un sexto usuario este ya no podrá y necesitara que uno de los 5 usuarios anteriores salga de la aplicación para poder acceder, investigando un poco al respecto vi partes donde decía que podría usar **Firebase** para algo así aunque no estoy seguro que sea una opción muy puntual ya que debo utilizar la base de datos de **Firebase** y en este caso necesito validar con mi propia base de datos **MySQL**

Ahora explicando lo que se me ocurrió pues se me ocurre crear un campo en una tabla de **MySQL** donde tenga una cantidad de usuarios que permito en mi app a primera instancia lo encuentro bastante sencillo ya que lo único que aria es consultar el numero de usuarios que están disponibles para usar la app, el problema es cuando uno de los usuarios se salga en ese momento la cantidad de usuarios disponibles obvio se queda en 5 pero la cantidad de usuarios activos debería bajar de 5 a 4 entonces veo que existe un método llamado `onPause();` que se ejecuta cuando la aplicación entra en segundo plano y `onDestroy();` cuando la aplicación se destruye completamente, lo que se me ocurrió es actualizar los usuarios activos cuando se ejecuten alguno de estos dos métodos.

Pero como lo había mencionado no se como comenzar o si es la mejor idea o si mejor utilizo **Firebase** y la forma en que lo aria, espero me puedan instruir en el tema y perdón por el exhaustivo texto espero que se haya comprendido, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Desde luego que Firebase tiene la posibilidad de detectar usuarios unicos estan usando tu app al mismo tiempo. Te sugiero revisar acerca de Firestore!

Comment: Recientemente aplique dependencias de firebase a uno de mis proyectos. Te suguiero utilizar el modulo de autenticacion de Firebase para aprovechar estas extras: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth
es facil de implementar con los pasos que ayi te muestra.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

creo que no necesitas saber cuántos usuarios están usando la aplicación en tiempo real, sino que lo que necesitas es un throttle para limitar el uso de la misma.

lo que yo haría sería almacenar en el momento del login, la información del tiempo de vida del token.

```
user_id | login_time | exp_time
12345   | 2022-03-30 | 2022-03-31
```

y al momento de que un nuevo usuario haga login validar cuantas sesiones activas quedan en la BD.

para atacar el tema de los abandonos, si una session no se reporta en los últimos 5 minutos, la considero como cerrada y la elimino de la BD.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta moscoquera una pregunta un throttle es es una especia de implementación externa o a que te refieres exactamente con eso?

Comment: hola @AdielMoran, un throttle, para ponerlo en un caso práctico, es como un semáforo, en tu caso por lo que veo, lo que quieres es que al existir N sesiones abiertas, no se permiten mas sesiones. la diferencia, sería que no dependieras de un servicio externo como firebase, sino que tu mismo lleves el control de las sessiones "activas".